# library Armen101 / AudioRecordView: chunks/ bars don't appear anymore

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio-recording

I'm using the library https://github.com/Armen101/AudioRecordView to visualize voice recording. That worked fine for a while, but when I reorganized the layout, the `AudioRecordView` stopped showing the chunks. The view is still visible (when I set to background to red I see the red view), the amlitude is still calculated correctly (between 0 and 28000) and when I call the `update` method, the view is not null. I also only have 1 `AudioRecordView` so I can't update the wrong one.

Here is the xml of the `AudioRecordView`:

```
 <com.visualizer.amplitude.AudioRecordView
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/audioRecordView"
    android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:background="@color/colorRed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:chunkAlignTo="center"
    app:chunkColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:chunkMaxHeight="48dp"
    app:chunkMinHeight="20dp"
    app:chunkRoundedCorners="true"
    app:chunkSoftTransition="false"
    app:chunkSpace="1dp"
    app:chunkWidth="2dp"
    app:direction="leftToRight" />
```

Here is the `update` call:

```
timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
                val currentMaxAmplitude = mediaRecorder?.maxAmplitude ?: 0
                audioRecordView!!.update(currentMaxAmplitude) 
        }
    }, 0, 100)
```

And again: when the timer runs, the amplitude is correctly calculated and the `AudioRecordView`is not null.

The view jsut doesn't draw the chunks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to call `runOnUiThread` explicitly:

```
timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            val currentMaxAmplitude = mediaRecorder?.maxAmplitude ?: 0
            activity.runOnUiThread {
                audioRecordView?.update(currentMaxAmplitude / 2)
            }

        }
    }, 0, 100)
```

No idea why it worked before, I always assume dthe library makes sure it updates on the UI thread in the `update`method. Maybe I used a new version of the library?! I'm on `'com.github.Armen101:AudioRecordView:1.0.5'`now,...